# iphone tableview data dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview, dynamic

I have a UIPickerView in my application.
 Also there is a table view. Based on the value I select in picker my table values should change.

I am getting values from response. how can I dynamically populate the table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'I am getting values from response'. What do you mean? What type of values? Please be more clear.

Comment: put some code " How you get value" and code for cellForIndex... method

Comment: you need to accept answers to your previous questions, it is discouraging for people to put effort into answering your questions if you can't be bothered to accept their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is, you select a value from picker , based on which you call some web-service. There you get some response and show that result in tableview. So the best way is, get the response data from webservice(the data you want to show in table) and store it in some dictionary. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, show the value in cell from this dictionary. The `reloadData` will help you to reload the `tableView` once you got the response.

Answer (score 1):

once you get selected value, reload the table by

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```